# C++ Using native dlls in the C++ project

Tags: c++

I thought this should be straightforward but I am running into a bunch of linker errors like so:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file '...\Debug\Utils.lib'   ...\LINK

where Utils is one of the C++ projects I want to keep as DLL.

If I change **Configuration Properties**->**Configuration Type** to **Static Library(.lib)** everything compiles and runs fine, but if I use .dll then its not working.

The whole solution is native C++ with the main project being a win32 console application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your library (Utils.lib) is not assembled as DLL and changes in console application project (that uses library) will not help.
Read carefully [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) to see features of DLL's creation and usage.

Answer (score 0):

It you try to link a .lib against another .lib, it doesn't really link. Instead, this instructs the final link to use both libraries.

For a DLL, this can't work, as the runtime linker cannot link the original .LIB. That means the link has to happen when the DLL is compiled.

As a result, a DLL project needs to have the .LIB directories set right.

Comment: I am not using any libs though... For simplicity's sake I've created a new empty Win32 project which builds to .exe. In the same solution I've created another Win32 project which builds to .dll. Now I add reference to the .dll project in my .exe project and receive **LNK1104: cannot open file ..\TestDLL.lib'** error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MichaelNaumov: " Not using any libs" ? If you want to use a DLL at runtime, the compiler must know which functions are in the DLL. That's achieved by statically linking against the _import librry_ of that DLL, which is a small .LIB.